# How to import css file with @import rule inside css with base_url

Tags: php, css, import

How can I import a css file with @import rule using a `<?=base_url()?>` inside a string.

```
@import '<?=base_url()?>resources/css/news/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: I think your code will do!

Answer (score 1):

```
@import url('resources/css/news/bootstrap.min.css');
```